# What are the different parts of speech of 这么?

Tags: grammar

这么 is listed in the dictionary as a pronoun.

她这么漂亮！

今天这么热。

这张桌子原来就这么放的。

有些人不是这么想。

他们必须这么说。

Is 这么 in all these sentences a pronoun? Can 这么 be an adverb too?

Comment: the most common use I'd say is an adverb, 这么 and 那么 are like the word "so" in English, so "她这么漂亮" would be translated as "she is so pretty". the more nuanced meaning is "like this" or "in this way"

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not always a pronoun. "这么/那么" can be an adverb, and you already gave the examples.

她这么漂亮！she is **SO** beautiful! （adverb）

今天这么热。Today is **SO** hot. (adverb)

这张桌子原来就这么放的。The desk was put **in this way** (pronoun)

有些人不是这么想。Some people doesn't think about it **this way** (pronoun)

他们必须这么说。They have to say **that** (pronoun)